# I have imported an excel file into Jupyter, columns are stacked

Tags: python, excel, pandas, import

I imported the excel file, but for some reason the columns are not displayed horizontally. The ones displayed below have their own indexes.
How can I rectify this?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `print(energy)` to `display(energy)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `print` in Jupyter for a pandas DataFrame. Use `display()` instead of `print()` to render html-formatted DataFrames. Or you can just type `energy` and that would work too.